# how to get a 3 Tables side by side in a Table using HTML

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller, html5

I have three different tables with part number ,Pricing Request and Quantity.All these table should be created in a table with different tables.I have used html table but it comes on below the other instead of side by side.

code written :

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="RFQ__c" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >

 <apex:form id="RF">

 <h1> <apex:sectionHeader title=" SALES REQUEST FOR QUOTE FORM(RFQ)"  /> </h1>

 <apex:pageblock >

  <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information">

  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Name}" label="Customer Name"/>

  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.AccountType__c}"/>

 <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Date__c}"/>

 <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Response_Needed_By_Date__c}"/>

 <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Expected_Order_Date__c}"/>

 <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.ProbabilityOf_Order_With_Requested_Price__c}"/>

<apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Comments__c}"/>

</apex:pageBlockSection>

  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Price Request Details">

  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.RFQOpportunity__r.AccSegment__c}"/>

  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.RFQOpportunity__r.AccApplication__c}"/>

  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.RFQOpportunity__r.Persona__c}"/>

  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.RFQOpportunity__r.AccSegment__c}"/>

  <html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <h1><caption></caption></h1>
  <tr>
    <th>Part Numbers</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>BXRC-30E4000-F-03</td></tr>
    <tr> <td>BXRC-30E4000-F-03</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>

          </table>
      </body>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <h1><caption>Pricing Requests</caption></h1>
  <tr>
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <th>4Q13</th>
    <th>1Q14</th>
    <th>2Q14</th>
    <th>3Q14</th>
    <th>4Q14</th>
    <th>1Q15</th>
<th>2Q15</th>
<th>3Q15</th>
<th>4Q15</th>
<th>1Q16</th>
<th>2Q16</th>
<th>3Q16</th>
<th>4Q16</th>
<th>1Q17</th>
<th>2Q17</th>
<th>3Q17</th>
<th>4Q17</th>
<th>1Q18</th>
<th>2Q18</th>
<th>3Q18</th>
<th>4Q18</th>
<th>1Q19</th>
<th>2Q19</th>
<th>3Q19</th>
<th>4Q19</th>
<th>1Q20</th>
<th>2Q20</th>
<th>3Q20</th>
<th>4Q20</th>




  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>


  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>


  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>


  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>


  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>


  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
   <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>


  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <h1><caption>Quantity</caption></h1>
  <tr>
    <th>Total Quantity</th>
    <th>4Q13</th>
    <th>1Q14</th>
    <th>2Q14</th>
    <th>3Q14</th>
    <th>4Q14</th>
    <th>1Q15</th>
<th>2Q15</th>
<th>3Q15</th>
<th>4Q15</th>
<th>1Q16</th>
<th>2Q16</th>
<th>3Q16</th>
<th>4Q16</th>
<th>1Q17</th>
<th>2Q17</th>
<th>3Q17</th>
<th>4Q17</th>
<th>1Q18</th>
<th>2Q18</th>
<th>3Q18</th>
<th>4Q18</th>
<th>1Q19</th>
<th>2Q19</th>
<th>3Q19</th>
<th>4Q19</th>
<th>1Q20</th>
<th>2Q20</th>
<th>3Q20</th>
<th>4Q20</th>




  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$01</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$02</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>


  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$03</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>


  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$04</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>$05</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$06</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$07</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$08</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$09</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$10</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>
<tr>
     <td>$0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>


  </apex:pageBlockSection>

  </apex:pageblock>

  </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you use apex repeat?

Comment: @regal:how does it work ,no idea about it exactly

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this right, you can acheive this using tables within tables.

```
<table border="2">
   <td>
        <table> 
           <td>Part Numbers</td>
        </table>
   </td>
   <td>
        <table>
            <td>Pricing Requests</td>
        </table>
   </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I just had to do this on a project myself ... here is what I did (# tables is variable and each has same layout). Note use of css float to place side-by-side. The VF doc is explicit in that multiple `apex:dataTable` within `apex:panelGrid` will not work side-by-side.

```
<apex:pageBlock id="multiTblPgBlk" title="myTitle">
    <apex:repeat value="{!myListOfTbls}" var="tbl">
     <apex:outputPanel layout="block" 
            style="float:left;padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px">  <!--  use css float left to put side-by-side -->
        <apex:dataTable value="{!tbl.tblRows}" var="row" columns="2" columnsWidth="80px,260px" id="dispTbl">
         <apex:facet name="header"><apex:outputText value="{!tbl.label}"/></apex:facet>
         <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">MyCol00</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!row.fld0}"/>
         </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
         <apex:facet name="header">MyCol01</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!row.fld1}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:dataTable>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:repeat>          

</apex:pageBlock>
```